# JSON deserialize array of long to list<long> not working

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json-deserialization

I have a controller giving JSON as response.

```
public ActionResult Messages()
{
   var Ids = new List<long>() { 1,2,3,4 };
   var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Ids);
   return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Results in this JSON being responded:

> [1,2,3,4]

At the client-side I'm trying to deserialize that JSON back to a List using :

```cs
using (_HttpResponse = client.SendAsync(_HttpRequest).Result)
{
    _HttpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var _ResponseContent = await _HttpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var Ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<long>>(_ResponseContent);
}
```

_ResponseContent becomes:

```
"[1,2,3,4]"
```

Mark the " around the array.
At deserialization I get the following exception :

> Error converting value "[1,2,3,4]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]'. Path '', line 1, position 11.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It seems to work just fine https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/GmgngC

Comment: This should work just fine, have you made sure your json is **actually** like that?

Comment: Does the string **contain** those quotes? Or is that just how the debugger shows it? What does `_ResponseContent.Length` tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method convert your list of numbers to be a JSON **string** and you are returning that string from your action method. So basically your output is not really a json array of numbers, but a string like this

```
"[1,2,3,4]"
```

You should simply use the `Json` method which returns the correct json array

```
public ActionResult Messages()
{
    var Ids = new List<long>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    return Json(Ids, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This method should return a response like this

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

With this response, your other client code should be able to properly deserialize it to a list of numbers

Comment: This change did it ! Thx.